Execute SQL function with jakarta.persistence.Query throw commit error

what I want: I need to execute a SQL function (very large) with jakarta.persistence.Query.
what I do:

 @Transactional
    public int executeRunFunctions() {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(loadQuery("/script4.sql"), Long.class);
        System.out.println(query == null);
        System.out.println("---- " + query.executeUpdate());
        return 0;
    }


what I get:

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: JDBC exception executing SQL [...my sql function..]
[ERROR: invalid transaction termination
  Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 113 at COMMIT] [n/a]


what I try:
With the settings:

spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true

And I get:
Step failed
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection

But, function executed successfully, in my DB process worked.
Without this settings, my SQL script (not function) with drop&create table work successfully.
Whereas with this settings it really worked with this error ('Unable to commit against JDBC Connection') too.
I use several combinations this settings and I make this:
I left one setting 'spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true' and surround problematic code in try-catch.
Help me please, how I can make it right?

function skeleton:

DO
$$
    DECLARE
       ....
    BEGIN
       .....

        FOR ....
            LOOP
               ....
                IF NOT FOUND
                THEN
                    ....
                    UPDATE....
                    SET ....
                    COMMIT;
                    CONTINUE;
                END IF;
                
                IF...
                THEN
                    ....
                    UPDATE....
                    SET ....
                    COMMIT;
                    CONTINUE;
                END IF;
                ....
                FOR ... IN 1 .. ...
                    LOOP
                        BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO ....
                            VALUES (....
                            UPDATE....
                            SET .....
                            EXIT;
                        EXCEPTION
                            WHEN .... THEN
                                RAISE WARNING ....
                        END;
                        IF ......
                        THEN
                            ROLLBACK;
                            UPDATE....
                            SET ....,
                            ......
                            EXIT;
                        END IF;
                    END LOOP;
                COMMIT;
            END LOOP;
    END;
$$;```


What does your script look liike? If the script contains multiple statements, this is not the way to execute that.

I edit question and add function skeleton

Executing a DDL like this won't work (also what would happen if you executed it already). I don't get why you are executing the script and create the function instead of executing the function.

I don't understand:  executing the script and create the function. I don't create function, I have it in loadQuery("/script4.sql")  and I showed the structure of the function. I can't change sql-function, that I must change java-code?

I asked you for the content of script4.sql and you responded with the code of the function. So I assume that that is the content of the file. If it isn't then again add the content of the file.

Yes, it's (function skeleton) content of the file script4.sql.

So the script is creating the function not executing it (well maybe afterwards). Why isn't this function just part of the database and you can just call it?

script4 it's just name, actually I can replace replace with String. Any sql query is executed using this function  query.executeUpdate().

It is not about the name of the script it is about the content of the script. That is a ddl statement creating /declaring the function. The function should be in the database so you can call it using a SQL query. Even if you put the content of the script in as a String it would fail as it isn't a single statement.

Understand, I use this sql in DBuiver manually: I past this sql and press play. As I understand it: this sql doesn't create function in DB, but it only  executed and returns the result. And what I must do with my problem?
